# Exception While using cefsharp in asp.net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, chromium-embedded, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

im trying to use CEF in Code Behind in asp.net Project 
the problem is it keeps Giving This Error

> Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

even I have All CEF Files Copied To /bin Folder Of the Project. 
this Error Occur Just After installing Cef From Nuget Package
i have Also Tried CEFSharp.Offscreen and CEFSharp.WinForms (it Works For Windows Applications But Not For Web But I have Tried Anyway)

Comment: Search the Github project, this topic has been covered before

Comment: can you provide me a link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even this is Old Question i Will Add answer for it
after a lot of research i have found that cefSharp Require a UI (Windows Interface) to Work So Using CefSharp With Asp.net Is Not Possible

Comment: The OffScreen version doesn't require a UI and can be used from a console application and windows service. You should also be able to use it within an Asp.net core application. ASP.Net can be made to work and there is a very old example at https://github.com/flole/CefSharp.AppDomain